# How get columns fixed in a html-table and JUST one column relative?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a html-table with 7 columns. Why are the width relative in stead of fixed. If I gave the class the properties:
style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;"
... then all column has the same width...

What do I have to do that columns gets the right width?

- labelD => width: 80px;
- labelN => width: 50px;
- and labelT => width: 100%; The rest of the table...

```css
.label {
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.labelD {
    width: 80px;
}

.labelN {
    width: 50px;
}

.labelT {
    width: calc(100% - 330px);
}

.list {
    border: hidden 1px #e8eef4;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table class="list">
        <tr>
            <th class="label labelD">Date</th>
            <th class="label labelN">Note1</th>
            <th class="label labelN">Note2</th>
            <th class="label labelT">Title</th>
            <th class="label labelN">Note3</th>
            <th class="label labelN">Note4</th>
            <th class="label labelN">Note5</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please include your HTML code as text, not an image. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Than the html-code as text. I can't use "<" or  ">"... So I change them as "[" or "]".  That was the reason for creating an image.

Comment: I can't. Maybe someone else. The  < and > will disappear...

Comment: You aren't listening. _Use the editor_ to format your code properly. How do you think everyone else does it?

Comment: Thank you I found how... but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`.labelT { width: calc(100% - 330px); }`

Every column will need a width though.

Comment: Sorry gives the same result.

Comment: `width: calc(100% - 330px);` You need to minus all the other cols from 100%

Comment: You mean this result:    width: calc(100% - 330px); ? Sorry this gives the same result...

Comment: Did you put that on the correct class? Updated my answer.  The `.label` class can be ignored.

Comment: The code is in the code-snippet.